# Eclipse Libgdx android project doesn't export AndroidLauncher anymore

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a libgdx-android project in eclipse which I have been exporting successfully for weeks now. Today I noticed something strange when starting my apk:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{at.test.game.android/at.test.game.android.AndroidLauncher}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "at.test.game.android.AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/at.test.game.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/at.test.game.android-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "at.test.game.android.AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/at.test.game.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/at.test.game.android-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505)
... 10 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: at.test.game.android.AndroidLauncher
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

When examining the generated APK i noticed that the content of my src folder is not part of the APK src folder which means everything including "AndroicLauncher.class" is missing.

Since there are no options I could configure when exporting the android application I'm pretty lost why this is suddenly happening now.
Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** I didn't notice that since I added the google play billing api the build configuration file would not get build anymore. Yesterday I wiped all the binary files by cleaning my projects now when trying to export my application my ApplicationLauncher class wouldn't get compiled. The solution was to start eclipse as administrator which allows the google billing api to get processed.